Getting a mutable struct reference to an element of a vector of boxes
I have a vector containing Box<dyn ...> elements. I want to run a method on the underlying struct that is guaranteed to be of the correct type. My current approach is to attempt to downcast_mut to my struct type, but it looks like I'm missing a step:
use std::any::Any;

trait T {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {}

impl S {
    pub fn doit(&mut self) { println!("AAAAA!"); }
}

impl T for S {}

fn main() {
    let mut boxes: Vec<Box<dyn T>> = vec![Box::new(S {})];
    for item in boxes.iter_mut() {
        let mut x = (item as &mut dyn Any).downcast_mut::<S>();
        println!("{x:?}");
        x.iter_mut().for_each(|s| s.doit());
        break;
    }
}

I'm not getting an error, but x is None when I print it.

Changing item to &mut *item in item as &mut dyn Any did not change the result.
I've also tried making T an explicit sub-trait of Any with trait T: Any {} to no effect.

How can I mutably borrow a Box<dyn T> if I know it's an S and use it as such?

downcast_mut instead of downcast_ref?

@eggyal. I just realized that, but have a different issue now. Gonna edit.

@eggyal. Let me know if this makes more sense

Ah, sorry I should have looked closer.  I see now that item is an &mut Box<dyn T>, which you're casting as &mut dyn Any and then attempting to downcast to &mut S—this fails because the concrete type is Box, not S.  What you want to do is first dereference item e.g. &mut **item as &mut dyn Any—but this won't work either for two reasons: 1. dyn T is not guaranteed to implement dyn Any, Any would need to be a supertrait of T for that to be a valid "trait upcast"; and 2. trait upcasting is not yet supported.

The usual suggestion in these cases is to add a fn as_s_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut S> { None } to your trait T, which S can override just by returning Some(self).

@eggyal. Would you consider writing up an answer? I implemented your suggestion by adding another trait U that has doit in it and returning Option<&mut dyn U> instead of just S, but otherwise the concept is identical.

I don't know if this can create undefined behavior, but it works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd25a72f3b89a04fcfd47a28627ebbd5

@trueequalsfalse: think that may well be sound, but it could be a little bit simpler.
